# Edit Data in DataGridView with LinQ to entity as datasource

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

[image: Entity Models]

This is a simple models that I am working on , three tables.

 I need to Have a DataGridView that show the ClientID , **ClientName** , Current_Balance , Required , Expected , Paid , Difference_Req_Paid_Difference _Expe_Paid,DateWeekly and this DataGridView enable me to add new rows and to edit current 
 as DataSource I have used a LinQ like

```
visibledataGridView1.DataSource = context.Payments.Select(x => 
    new {  x.Client.ClientName,
x.ClientID,
x.Current_Balance,
x.Paid,x.Expected,
x.Required,
x.Difference_Exce_Paid,
x.Difference_Req_Paid 
});
```

but this only show thid doesn't allow me to add or to edit.

Comment: Don't use an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved with a little trick , with checking in the database if the current PaymentID , it will modifie by a sp that update the row in the database 
if not it will create a new object from Payment and add it to Payments.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out, i hope its help

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

http://www.idothink.com/2009/06/datagridview-editmode.html